# Inserting data in to a table add already inserted data

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 tables `tblpermission`, `tblgroup`, `tblassigngrouppermission`. Then I have a design there have two comboboxes for selecting group and permission. After select I add it to a listview. Then I save it, at that time it will go to the table `tblassigngrouppermission`.

That table has columns such as `assign id` (default increment), `groupid`, `permission id`. All are correctly added to the table. After that saving if I select the same group for assign permission. Then I select already assigned permission and click save it added to the table. But I need there not add the already assigned permission to the table.

How can I do this?

Comment: please give me a repaly please............

Comment: You're **NOT** clear at all - I cannot understand from your question what the heck you're doing, and where you're having issues...... you need to rephrase that question

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving the data back to `tblassigngrouppermission` you will have to check the presence of `group_id` and `permission_id` in the table.

if they are present you will have to update `tblassigngrouppermission` else you will have to insert in `tblassigngrouppermission`

Comment: how can i check and where i check?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stored procedure you could do this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(Select permissionId From tblassigngrouppermission 
              Where groupId=@GroupID AND permissionId=@permissionId)
Begin

   INSERT INTO tblassigngrouppermission(groupId,permissionId) Values(@groupId, @PermissionID)
End
```

You can also check from your code

==> Write a function that test if the permission already exist

```
bool GroupPermissionExists(int groupId, int permissionId)
{
   //Select Where GroupId=groupId AND PermissionID=permissionId
}

if(!GroupPermissionExists(10, 123))
{
    AddPermissionToGroup(10, 123);
}
```

Comment: Actually ithis is my save code where i can check the condition

Comment: ITS NOT HELPFULL TO ME I AM USING LINQ QUERY

Comment: You can substitute linq anywhere in that code, it's not technology-specific. Also, you did not tag your question with LINQ????